# Connecting multiple Xbox 360 for multiplayer?

Tags: xbox-360

I have two Xbox 360 and I heard you could make two systems act like one. I was wondering how that works.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for system link play ([KB article from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910583/en-us)), which is an alternative multiplayer mode. Wikipedia has a [list of games compatible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Xbox_360_System_Link_games) with that mode.